# Get the length of jQquery Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to count the length of an Ajax response done in jQuery. The response is in JSON format and only contains a single string. I get the value but have no idea how to count the length of this string.

Here's my code :

```
var tempId;
$.ajax({
    url: "<?=base_url();?>index.php/sell/decoder",
    type: "POST",
    data: {'str' : sometext},
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(response) {
        tempId = response; // This gives me a return value as a string. For example = 153
        alert(tempId.length); // But this returns "undefined". What should I do to get the length?
    }
});
```

Here's the structure of the response header:

```
Connection  Keep-Alive 
Content-Length  2
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Fri, 06 Jul 2012 08:12:12 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=86
Server  Apache
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.10
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of the response

Comment: If you could `alert(tempId.length);` why not `alert(tempId);` too, also you could use `console.log(tempId)` to check it in console.

Comment: Do a console.log(response) and show us the result. And, why are you using async: false? Don't do that, because synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334341/jquery-javascript-json-to-string-variable-dump

Comment: @MohammadAdil you are definitely right. thanks. I never noticed that thing :-) But, is there another way to get the length of the value contained in Json object?

Comment: Do a console.log(response) as the first line of the success function. And show the output as is. I say as is because you said the response is a string, but in your comment you say its 153, which is a integer. "153" would be the string. It may have been a typo, which is why am asking for the response as is.

Comment: here's the structure of the response header:
`Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Length 2
Content-Type text/html
Date Fri, 06 Jul 2012 08:12:12 GMT
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=86
Server Apache
X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.10`

Comment: @Angel I do that to solve the previous problem I met. I need to put the response value into variable tempId in order to use it outside the ajax success. If I turn on the async and call the tempId, all i get is undefined.

Comment: True, but you should move the logic to the success function of the ajax, or have a function call in the success, to take advantage of the async of ajax.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do an if condition then convert it to string first, then count the length as needed.

```
success: function(response) {
    if(response){       
      alert( (response + '').length );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Or convert your value (I guess it is an integer) to string:

```
tempId.toString().length
```

Comment: this is more elegant solution. But I noticed you have a typo there :-). thank you

Comment: yeah, `.toString()` is the func

Comment: **tempId.toString().length** will work only when the **tempID** is not a type of object.

**[{name:'test'}].toString()** will return [object Object].

and **[{name:'test'}].toString().length** will return 15

Answer (score 0):

`tempId.String.length` worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the response is not an object then

```
success: function(response) {
    if(response){       
      alert( (response + '').length );
    }
}
```

will work well.

but if response will be in the form of Object like

```
[{name:'some-name',details:[....something]}]
```

I would suggest use below code

```
success: function(response) {
     length=0;
     if(response){       
        length=JSON.stringify(response).length;
     }
    console.log(length)
}
```

I think this code will work like a charm for you.